# Pages '09 flags file as modified after printing

Tags: pages, bug, macos

I'm using `Pages '09` with Mountain Lion (10.8.3).

Every time I open a file to just print it and don't make any modifications, Pages '09 flags it as modified.

If I just want to close <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> this file, and to be sure I didn't make any unwanted modifications, I get this window:

[image: test Pages warning window].

- The first choice makes me think I made an unwanted modification.
- The third one is inappropriate if I didn't made modifications.
- The second choice bring me back to the same state: document to close
  and next the same warning window.

Is there an easy way to suppress this irrelevant warning window in such
a case, i.e. when I didn't made any modification and such a warning window is neither necessary nor usefull.

Is this bug fixed in any recent version of `Pages`?

Answer (score 1):

Since the file *is* being modified, there's no way to suppress this.

You can notify Apple that you would like this feature implemented using their Pages feedback page:

- http://www.apple.com/feedback/pages.html

Comment: → grgarside: thank you for your attempt to help. The bug is reported to Apple since more than 2 years. I'm here talking of a situation where `I` clearly `didn't` made any modification to my file.
I'm not talking of modifications made either by the software or the system which I don't care of, and moreover I don't want to be bothered with. Otherwise, you easily imagine that any simply opened file should be flagged as modified (think of access time ☺).